How do I test the output script generated by custom MigrationBuilder extension in EF
Alright, let me see if I can explain this right without sharing out the code I have.
Given:
public static void UpdateStuff(this MigrationBuilder builder)
{
      builder.Sql($"DELETE FROM {tableAttribute.Name}")
      // Do a bunch of reflection to figure out table structure
      // Do a bunch of reflection to read values in a static class
      // Build InsertData
      builder.InsertData(
        tableAttribute.Name, 
        columns: propertyNames, 
        values: permissionsData);
}

Now I need to create a XUnit test that will "run" this, and get the resulting SQL script that I will compare with another preloaded string (result.sql) and see if they match.
Then:
[Fact]
public void UpdateStuff_Returns_A_Valid_SQL()
{
    var builder = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationBuilder(null);
    builder.UpdateStuff();
    // Assert results
}

Initially I thought that I could create a class that inherited from Migration just so I could instantiate it and pass the builder to Up and then somehow get the generated script out of it, but I am not sure about that.
Has anyone gone through this process and would know a little bit more about how I should go about this, I search for a little while but I can really find a good example that I could follow. Any great ideas?
